# Ignite avoids rebalancing using secretly kept offheap data

Tags: ignite

Steps to create situation:

1. configure Ignite 2.14.0 with `backups=1` and no persistence
2. start 3 server nodes (N1, N2, N3)
3. fill it with data somehow, occupying about 25% of heap (with onheap cache enabled)
4. kill N1
5. see (via grafana or something like that) that CacheSize and OffheapUsedSize and OffHeapEntriesCount on N2 and N3 raised by 50%, which is fine. TotalRebalancedBytes metric on N2 and N3 increased during this operation.
6. start N1 again
7. see that CacheSize and OffHeapEntriesCount of N2 and N3 are decreased back by 1/3, which is clear why, but OffheapUsedSize on N2 and N3 - isn't, it stays at 150% of initial value (!). TotalRebalancedBytes on N2 and N3 stay still.
8. kill N1 again
9. see that CacheSize and OffheapUsedSize on N2 and N3 raised by 50% again, but OffHeapEntriesCount stays at the same 150% of initial value. TotalRebalancedBytes stay still (!)
10. raise N1 again
11. restart N2 and N3, wait for rebalancing
12. kill N1 again
13. see (via grafana or something like that) that CacheSize and OffheapUsedSize and OffHeapEntriesCount on N2 and N3 raised by 50%, which is fine. TotalRebalancedBytes metric on N2 and N3 increased during this operation. exactly as in #5

So, we see that second and next loss of N1 doesn't require rebalancing of N2 and N3 until N2 and N3 keeps staying. and something occupy offheap space sneakily that time.

Looks like after first N1 loss, N2 and N3 remembers N1's data in their offheap even after its return. And this "memory" is reflected only in OffheapUsedSize, but not in OffHeapEntriesCount.

I've googled and browsed docs and haven't seen relevant information. What is the name of this feature? Where can I read about this feature? Is it configurable?

Comment: What about TotalRebalancedBytes on N1?

Comment: @AlexandrShapkin it's increased on steps 6, 10, 11. why do you ask?

Comment: Just curious, when N1 did a rebalance from other nodes. Anyway, to me everything except having a rebalance on step #9 looks expected.

Comment: @AlexandrShapkin you mean "not having rebalance on step #9"?

Answer (score 0):

`OffheapUsedSize`, i.e. offheap size doesn't shrink automatically. Ignite doesn't return memory back to the OS, instead it marks a memory page as free and ready for reuse. That's why there is no metrics' increase in step #9.
If you need your memory back to the OS, you can use [defragmentation](https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/administrators-guide/defragmentation#persistence-defragmentation) feature. Not sure if it's available in Apache Ignite though.

`OffHeapEntriesCount` represents actual number of records, despite the real memory consumption at the moment. That's the most informative metrics out of the rest to track real-time data distribution.

I suppose everything went as expected till the step #9. Personally, I'd expect `TotalRebalancedBytes` to increase on step #9 for N2 and N3, just like it was in #5. But, that might not be a case if you have manually configured [baseline topology.](https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/developers-guide/baseline-topology#baseline-topology-in-pure-in-memory-clusters) For in memory cache, auto-adjustment delay is 0 by default, meaning immediate baseline change and a rebalance trigger. If there is a non-zero delay, and it was a short restart, probably you could have skipped a rebalance.

> So, we see that second and next loss of N1 doesn't require rebalancing
> of N2 and N3 until N2 and N3 keeps staying. and something occupy
> offheap space sneakily that time.

But that diverge from the observation: third restart of N1 causes `TotalRebalancedBytes` to increase as you mentioned in the last step, doesn't it?

> TotalRebalancedBytes metric on N2 and N3 increased during this
> operation. exactly as in #5

Comment: "If you need your memory back to the OS". I don't. "I suppose everything went as expected till the step #9". All expected till this step to me too. that's a subject of a question. I didn't change baseline topology manually. auto-adjustment is default. "But that diverge from the observation: third restart of N1 causes TotalRebalancedBytes to increase as you mentioned in the last step, doesn't it?" it doesn't diverge, because third restart of N1 made after restarting N2 and N3 (and  release of unused offheap space on these nodes).

Comment: Both #5 and in #13 causes rebalance and both of them are fresh. In #7 they both are not fresh (had touched N1's data and have non-released offheap) and both doesn't rebalance.

Comment: I suppose there might be a mishandling or something. Cause in #6 N1 should be treated as a new node. I'll try to check the same later.

Comment: As I see from this scenario, N1 is treated as new node. What in scenario contradicts it?